# Receiving data in activity from a service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I've look at many solutions to other questions with similar issues but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. I understand that LocalBroadcast is a popular way to do this and I've spent time trying to implement it. At the moment, the receiver isn't declared in my manifest but from what I understand, that's what the `register` lines are for.

In my activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MyActivity", "onReceive");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        int current = intent.getIntExtra("test", 0);
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, current.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("MyActivity", "onResume()");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MyActivity.this).registerReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("currentUpdate"));
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.d("MyActivity", "onPause()");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MyActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

In the service I have a method defined:

```
private void sendNewBroadcast(Intent intent, int current){
    intent.putExtra("test", current);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    Log.d("MyService", "new Broadcast sent from service");
}
```

and I use it like this elsewhere in the service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("currentUpdate");
sendNewBroadcast(intent, 5);
```

I've debugged and everything seems to be working except for the 'receiving' part. Am I missing something? The service is started in a different activity and is ongoing.

Comment: The action you've set on the `Intent` – `"test"` in `new Intent("test")` – does not match the action on the `IntentFilter` – `"currentUpdate"`.

Comment: @MikeM you're right, I've changed it and unfortunately no difference. OnReceive is still not triggering

Comment: With that setup, your `Activity` needs to be running in the foreground when the broadcast is sent. Is it?

Comment: Also, `LocalBroadcastManager` does not work across processes. Are the `Activity` and `Service` running in the same process? That is, do either have a `process` attribute specified on their elements in the manifest?

Comment: @MikeM, that did it. I wasn't aware they had to be running in the same process, it's working now. Will accept your answer if you add it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the action `String` on the broadcast `Intent` needs to match the action set on the `IntentFilter` you're registering the Receiver with. Originally, they were different, but it was possibly just a typo.

Secondly, `LocalBroadcastManager` does not work across processes. The `Activity` and the `Service` must be running in the same process to be able to use `LocalBroadcastManager`. If the `Service` needs to be in a separate process, you'll have to use some other mechanism; e.g., `Intent`s, broadcasts sent and received on a `Context`, some event bus implementation that supports IPC, etc.